# Replacing a terracotta drain pipe underneath the floor

Tags: basement, drain-waste-vent, rough-in

I started to trench to rough in a bathroom in the basement with 2" concrete floor and although the vertical stack is cast iron, underneath the basement floor I discovered the below the CI cleanout - it is all terracotta including connecting elbow.  My question is should I just leave well enough alone and tie into the terracotta pipe or should I replace the clay pipe with PVC?

Some more information - the house is a > 100 years old city row house rehab with no trees within a 50ft radius. I could trench out some more but with no real threat of root infiltration and its under a concrete floor is there a need?  If I were to go the replace the entire line with PVC and the CI stack isn't supported by risers nor is strapped every 4' and that is where I will tap out.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change this?

Comment: its about 120 years old and as a preventive measure...

Comment: If it still drains when you pour water into it, I wouldn't worry about it.